# Acces token is created using Identity.Server3.How to transfer token from asp.net 5 mvc login to Angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, oauth, openid, asp.net-core-mvc

I am able to generate token after successful login using ASP.net 5 and Identity server 3[OpenID Connect and OAuth]. As client Angular.js is used but the login is used with asp.net mvc6 login.
Now is it possible to pass this token to Angular app?
On the internet all the examples are logged in from angular application and successful login returns token,which is saved into header and local storage for further use.

Comment: Don't understand, what do you want to do. Why you don't pass token, saved into header after login in mvc 6 too?